# Add css to selected "items" jQuery filter

Tags: jquery, css, filtering

I am filtering my items with this script, but I need to add a `margin:0` to the actvive/selected items so thet they line up correctly.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul#filter a').click(function () {
        $(this).css('outline', 'none');
        $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');

        if (filterVal == 'all') {
            $('ul#items li.hidden').fadeIn('xslow').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {

            $('ul#items li').each(function () {
                if (!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $(this).fadeIn('xslow').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Help highly appreciated

========================

## EDITED HTML ADDED

the menu:

```
                        <ul id="filter">
                        <li class="current"><a href="#">All</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item6</a></li>
                </ul>
```

and the items:

```
                        <ul id="items">
                        <div class="span12">

                        <li class="item1 span4">
                        <img src="images/item.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </li>

                        <li class="item2 span4">
                        <img src="images/item.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </li>

                        <li class="item3 span4">
                        <img src="images/item.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </li>

                        <li class="item4 span4">
                        <img src="images/item.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </li>

                        <li class="item5 span4">
                        <img src="images/item.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </li>

                        <li class="item6 span4">
                        <img src="images/item.jpg" alt=""/>
                        </li>

                        </div>
                        </ul>
```

As you can see I'm using TwitterBootsrap 2.X
I am aready using the nth-child selector to to remove the margin on certain .span's. so that the items line correctly in different rows.

Comment: how do you identify which items are active/selected?

Comment: If you post also HTML we can provide better help.

Comment: Do you mean to the 'current' item? i.e. the one firing the .click() function?

Answer (score 0):

If the element you are clicking is your active element and `current` is your active class, then try this:

Add `margin:0px` to current class.

```
.current { margin : 0px !important; }
```

Now add current class to active element and remove it from siblings.

```
$(this).parent().addClass('current'); // add current class to active element 
$(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('current'); // remove active class from sibling elements.
```

Comment: If this is the item he meant, he can take out this line: `$(this).css('outline', 'none');` and just add that to the `.current` class as well `outline:none;`.

Comment: sorry for posting my issue incomplete. as you can see in the updated post fiddling with .current will not do what I need as that is part of the navigation/menu

Comment: Create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)  for better understanding. I am still not able to get it.